# Get country from city and state

Tags: google-api, geolocation

I am storing the city and state of a user in our database. I want to get the country from the info I have. What can I use to achieve the same from the city and state? Is there a feature in Google API for the same?

Answer (score 0):

https://restcountries.eu

This might be a suiteable solution, haven't tried it yet though.

Or are you looking for a googleAPI-only solution?

greetings
Moritz Büttner